# Are there any texts that mention viruses or dinosaurs or black holes or electricity or chromosomes or explain that the stars are suns etc?

Tags: bible, science

From what I've understood, there's a lot more literature than just the Bible. So does anyone know if there are texts that mention anything about viruses, dinosaurs, electricity, magnetism or life on other planets or rainbows or the function of the heart ([which even 16th century medicos didn't know](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/history/magazine/2018/01-02/history-william-harvey-medicine-heart/)) or anything about the universe as we know of it today? The Old Testament mentions a lot of people who had access to God. Theoretically, any heavenly interaction with God or angels should have revealed more about the universe. Since it is believed that [statements from the Bible were misinterpreted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_affair#Bible_argument), leading to Galileo's words not being accepted, perhaps there would be texts that could have contained more information.

People talk about dinosaurs mentioned in the Bible ([behemoth and leviathan](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job%2040&version=NIV)), but we know that humans didn't exist at the same time as dinosaurs.

Some people point to yeast etc. to say that the Bible does [mention microbes](https://fae.adventist.org/essays/31Bcc_183-210.htm), but it does not actually explain anything about the microbes or viruses or bacteria or amoeba etc. It just describes phenomena that were commonly known, without understanding the reason behind it.

I know the scriptures are not meant to be scientific texts, but are for a more spiritual connection to God. All I'm asking is, whether there are any texts that mention any specific details *(not general details, even if the wording does not match the words we use today)* that God or any heavenly being who visited Earth, told humans? I'm pretty sure that curiosity would've been there. Every conversation won't have been about "how can I reach heaven?".
For example, an answer to a question could have been as simple as:

> "...that person is sick because there are creatures so tiny that we
> cannot see them. Those creatures attack the body internally and the
> body raises its temperature to try and kill those creatures"

... or while looking toward the sea, people could've been told about how the moon exerts a force on the water, causing the tides...or an explanation about just the basics of how volcanoes or earthquakes happen...or at least the basic explanation that the sun is a star...which if it was explained, we wouldn't have had the nursery rhyme *"Twinkle twinkle little star. How I wonder what you are?"*.

Comment: I can't find this again now to properly source it, but many years ago I read an article speaking of the astronomy of one of the many ancient scrolls that has been found in the Holy Land. It spoke of a major Biblical figure (I want to say Abraham but I'm not sure) having a discussion with an angel, asking where the light of the sun comes from. The question is serious enough that the angel has to take some precautions before showing him the answer, even in a vision, and ends up showing him a process recognizable to modern eyes as the fusion cycle. I really wish I could find that article again!

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate because we don't really support questions that ask "are there any verses that say X" here (because that becomes a heated debate of opinion), and because I think the linked question is a more interesting question: certainly some people claim the Bible makes scientific statements along those lines, but is that exegesis or eisegesis?

Comment: My question isn't about whether there are verses in the Bible that make scientific statements. My question is just about whether there are any recorded instances where the people who claim to have spoken to God or angels, would have asked more questions about the universe...or whether the heavenly beings would have mentioned something. That's it. This is not to debate anything. It's just to know if anything was ever mentioned. Not just in the Bible, but in any other literature.

Comment: @JohnDavid Ah, I can see how that is different from the other question. But all non-scriptural texts are way out of scope for this site! This site is just about formal organised Christianity, not anyone who has ever claimed to have spoken with God or angels.

Answer (score 1):

**Are there any texts that mention viruses or dinosaurs or black holes or electricity or chromosomes or explain that the stars are suns etc?**

Science and religion are supposed to be antagonists. History tells a more complicated story.

The Bible does not teach how the heavens go, but rather how to go to **Heaven**!

That is a huge difference.

To back up new scientific research biblically is not a new subject matter. It plagued both Cardinal Bellarmine and Galileo alike:

> Certainly Bellarmine used all the subjunctive reservation of which the Italian language was capable, that if some day it could be proved irrefutably that Copernicus was right, then one would have to go back and interpret the relevant biblical passages again. But he excluded the possibility of such proof.33 The doctrine that the Earth was in motion not only went against common sense, the Book of Joshua and the Psalms of David, but against Solomon himself; Solomon who had gained all his wisdom from God. For was not this ascribed to Solomon in the Book of Ecclesiastes: "The sun also ariseth, and the sun goeth down, and hasteth to his place where he arose." (Eccles. 1,5).
>
> The other reason for Galileo's strong stand, was that he believed he had just the indisputable, physical proof that Bellarmine required.
>
> But before he went public with his new proof he wanted to make certain of his home ground. Galileo decided to combine a theological and theoretical account with a courtly tribute and write an open letter to the Dowager Grand Duchess. The "Letter to Christina" ran to over forty pages, and circulated only in manuscript copies, as any attempt to publish it would have risked an open confrontation with the censor.
>
> In the letter he makes his position clear. Truth is one and indivisible. There can therefore be no conflict between the words of the Bible and natural revelations, but the Bible is written in a different language and has a different object: **it teaches us "how to go to heaven, and not how the heavens go.**" (***Non come va il cielo, ma come si va in cielo***.) **This implies that the Bible's words must be explained and interpreted.**

This implies that the Bible’s words must be explained and interpreted. And some interpretations seems simply to go sideways. We must also keep in mind the for such terms as viruses, black holes, chromosomes, dinosaurs and electricity did not exist in ancient Hebrew or Aramaic. In fact [electricity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity) did not exist as a modern element of usage until Benjamin Franklin showed up on the scene.

As I have already mentioned, many scientific words simply did not exist in ancient Hebrew and thus will not be found in the Bible. However certain glimmers of the subject at hand might be able to be found here and there. Please remember that not all will be in agreement here and interpretation in always that an interpretation.

Let us start with viruses and bacteria. There seems to be no explicit information on these phrases in Holy Writ, but some of the symptoms of these possibly seem to be written about.

Plagues are mentioned in the Scriptures one some occasions, yet what caused them remained unknown to the Ancient people of the Bible. Microscopes did not exactly exist in the good old days!

The sixth plague of Egypt bears an uncanny resemblance to the [Black Death](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Death) in the fact that the plague affecting Europe in the Middle Ages often produced boils caused by a bacteria called [***Yersinia pestis***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yersinia_pestis)

> [The Sixth Plague](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagues_of_Egypt)
>
> > Then the LORD said to Moses and Aaron, "Take handfuls of soot from a furnace and have Moses toss it into the air in the presence of Pharaoh. It will become fine dust over the whole land of Egypt, and festering boils will break out on men and animals throughout the land." — Exodus 9:8–9

Since the Ancients had no usage of microscopes, they know want divers plagues were. But they could not understand what caused them, be it a virus or a bacteria. The same logic goes for chromosomes.

The question of dinosaurs is a little more speculative, in that some interpretations of Scripture seems to possibly shed light on this subject. Not only are we dealing with interpretations here; we different translations come into play here too. We should keep in mind, paleontologists did not dig up the first dinosaur until 1819.

> [**Are Dinosaurs in the Bible?**](https://www.christianity.com/wiki/bible/what-does-the-bible-say-about-dinosaurs.html)
>
> Some scholars say yes, others no. This article takes the stance of the affirmative.
>
> Two instances in the Bible could possibly describe a dinosaur, or at least, a dinosaur-like creature. Some theologians will argue the author could have used hyperbole or metaphorical imagery, but if he chose to do so, he picked some rather odd images to describe mundane creatures.
>
> 1. Behemoth ([Job 40:15-24](https://www.christianity.com/bible/bible.php?ver=niv&q=job%2040%3A15-24))
>
> In Job, this creature is described as having a tail like a cedar and an herbivore diet. It also says this colossal beast had large bones like beams of bronze.
>
> From the portrayal in those verses, it seems as though the passage indicates a creature similar to a diplodocus. Some commentators try to say God had described a hippopotamus in this passage, but the depiction doesn’t seem to match up. Hippos, for instance, don’t have tails like cedars.
>
> 2. Leviathan ([Job 41](https://www.christianity.com/bible/bible.php?ver=niv&q=job%2041))
>
> By the next chapter, another creature is reported which some theologians have labeled a crocodile. However, once one hears the features of the leviathan, it doesn’t appear to add up.

The leviathan seems to have armor-plated skin that no hook can pierce. Like the behemoth, the author makes note of the strong limbs this animal possesses.

> [Psalm 104:26](https://www.christianity.com/bible/bible.php?ver=niv&q=psalms%20104:26) indicates the leviathan lived in water, which could point to why some people say it’s a crocodile. And [Isaiah 27:1](https://www.christianity.com/bible/bible.php?ver=niv&q=isaiah%2027:1) describes the leviathan as a twisting serpent.
>
> These may align with a crocodile, but Job ([Job 41:18-19](https://www.christianity.com/bible/bible.php?ver=niv&q=job%2041%3A18-19)) seem to indicate this creature literally breathed fire. Crocodiles and other similar reptiles have not been known to breathe fire. This may indicate a dragon-like species existed during Job’s time.

Interpretation and diverse translation weigh into one’s perspective. Two points here to illustrate my meaning here. Some versions state that unicorns existed. Oh, yes the Bible says so. But the word in English versions vary from unicorn to water buffaloes or an ox.

> [Re'em](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re%27em)
>
> Will the unicorn be willing to serve thee, or abide by thy crib? Canst thou bind the unicorn with his band in the furrow? or will he harrow the valleys after thee? Wilt thou trust him, because his strength is great? or wilt thou leave thy labour to him? Wilt thou believe him, that he will bring home thy seed, and gather it into thy barn?

Some Tibetan missionaries proposed the this mysterious creature is non other than the [**Tibetan antelope**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_antelope) because of the numerous legends surrounding this animal.

Another interesting story from the Bible is that of Tobias and the fish that wanted to eat him.

> [**Tobias Catches a Fish**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Tobit%206&version=GNT)
>
> 6 So Tobias and the angel started out toward Media, taking Tobias' dog along with them. They walked on until sunset, then camped by the Tigris River. 2 Tobias had gone down to wash his feet in the river, when suddenly a huge fish jumped up out of the water and tried to swallow one of his feet. Tobias let out a yell, 3 and the angel called to him,
>
> Grab that fish! Don't let it get away.
> Then Tobias grabbed the fish and dragged it up on the bank.
>
> 4 Cut the fish open, the angel instructed,
> and take out its gall bladder, heart, and liver. Keep these with you; they can be used for medicine, but throw away the guts.
>
> 5 Tobias did as the angel had told him. Then he cooked the fish, ate part of it, and salted the rest to take along with him.

To this date I am unable to locate any local legends as to what species of fish this might have been. Both Bible and legendary works come up black.

As for the existence of black holes and that stars are suns is irrelevant to God’s word in the Holy Bible as the inspired authors of God’s Word did not have telescopes and they wrote as they were inspired to do so.

The Bible teaches us **how to go to heaven, and not how the heavens go.** (Non come va il cielo, ma come si va in cielo.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if you read my question again, you'll see that I'm not interested in challenging anything written in the scriptures. It's just a question about whether there any recorded instances of the people who communicated with God or angels or Jesus, receiving any information about how the world works. I'm pretty sure that curiosity would've been there at the time, and there would've been simple ways to explain it to the people of that time. Anyway, from the replies, it seems like there's no info about it that we know of, so closing the question is fine.

Comment: @JohnDavid You should shorten your text for the purpose of clarity.

Comment: Glad you mentioned Galileo. +1 for "The Bible does not teach how the heavens go, but rather how to go to Heaven!"

Comment: @Lesley Thanks for the support, but I fear many simply over look this!

Comment: @KenGraham Shame the question was closed but the information remains for others to read.